# c# file read and send over socket

Tags: c#, networking, stream

This is how I send a file using a `NetworkStream`.

```
private void go()
{
    byte[] send = File.ReadAllBytes("example.txt");
    ns.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
}
```

`ns` is a `NetworkStream` of course.

Now I would like to know how I could receive and read an incoming `NetworkStream`?

I know that I need to specify a buffer to read from like this,

```
ns.Read(buffer,0,buffer.length).
```

but which buffer should be there?

Comment: Send the length of the buffer first and then when receiving, create a byte array of that size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is a stream based protocol, which means that there is no notation of application messages like in UDP. Thus you cannot really detect by TCP itself where an application message ends.

Therefore you need to introduce some kind of detection. Typically you add a suffix (new line, semicolon or whatever) or a length header.

In this case it's easier to add a length header since the chosen suffix could be found in the file data.

So sending the file would look like this:

```
private void SendFile(string fileName, NetworkStream ns)
{
    var bytesToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    var header = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length);
    ns.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
    ns.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
}
```

On the receiver side it's important that you check the return value from Read as contents can come in chunks:

```
public byte[] ReadFile(NetworkStream ns)
{
    var header = new byte[4];
    var bytesLeft = 4;
    var offset = 0;

    // have to repeat as messages can come in chunks
    while (bytesLeft > 0)
    {
        var bytesRead = ns.Read(header, offset, bytesLeft);
        offset += bytesRead;
        bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
    }

    bytesLeft = BitConverter.ToInt32(header, 0);
    offset = 0;
    var fileContents = new byte[bytesLeft];

    // have to repeat as messages can come in chunks
    while (bytesLeft > 0)
    {
        var bytesRead = ns.Read(fileContents, offset, bytesLeft);
        offset += bytesRead;
        bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
    }

    return fileContents;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! and if i would like also to send the name of the file and receive it in the other side? @jgauffin

Comment: Send another header indicating the size of the file name. i.e. <FileNameLengthHeader><FileName><BodyLengthHeader><Body>

Comment: You could also use the networking library in my Griffin.Framework: http://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.framework